# Pass template to controller render in twig

Tags: symfony, templates, model-view-controller, twig, sylius

I'm trying to build Login form popup and I want to render `LoginAction` controller in twig.

I'm getting error like:
`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Template is not configured.").`

My twig template:

```
{{ render(controller('SyliusUserBundle:Security:login'))}}
```

And in `Security.yml`

```
sylius_shop_login:
path: /login
methods: [GET]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.security:loginAction
    _sylius:
        template: "@SyliusShop/login.html.twig"
        logged_in_route: sylius_shop_account_dashboard
```

How to include template in twig controller render?

**Edit:**

Any other better approach to show login form in popup? My plan is to include `custom_login.html.twig` in Layout twig using `render(controller('SyliusUserBundle:Security:login'))`. But not able to send specific twig templete to controller.

Comment: You want to use the default login template or override it with your own login template?

Comment: I need to create login popup so need to override login template.

Comment: Did you follow this http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/template.html#how-to-customize-templates-by-overriding ?

Comment: Yes. So basically my requirement is to create new twig template (which includes popup model) for the same action (login action) and render that popup block in my layout.twig file. My aim is to render login form on load and display when user clicks on login link.

Comment: Do you have the same error when you try to render SyliusShopBundle:login.html.twig instead?

Comment: I have included only {{ render(controller('SyliusUserBundle:Security:login'))}} in twig. So by default it is taking default template and I'm getting above mentioned  error.